# html scraping in either batch or powershell

Tags: html, powershell, batch-file, web-scraping

I need to scrape the html of a site, which is launched off a .url file, then find a certain line, and grab every line below it to a certain point. An example of the html code is below:

```html
</p><ul><li>(None)</li></ul><h2><span style="font-size:18px;">Authorized Administrators and Users</span></h2><pre><b>Authorized Administrators&#58;</b>
jim (you)
    password&#58; (blank/none)
bob
    password&#58; Littl3@birD
batman
    password&#58; 3ndur4N(e&amp;home
dab
    password&#58; captain

<b>Authorized Users&#58;</b>
bag
crab
oliver
james
scott
john
apple
</pre><h2><span style="font-size:18px;">Competition Guidelines</span></h2>
```

I need to get all of the authorized administrators into a txt file, the authorized users into a txt file, and both into another txt file. Could this be accomplished with just batch and powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, as stated, **using a dedicated HTML parser is preferable**, but given the easily identifiable enclosing tags in your input (assuming there'll be no variations), you can get away with a regex-based solution.

Here's **a regex-based PSv4+ solution**, but note that it **relies on the input containing whitespace (line breaks, leading spaces) exactly as shown in your question**:

```bash
# $html is assumed to contain the input HTML text (can be a full document).
$admins, $users = (
  # Split the HTML text into the sections of interest.
  $html -split
    '\A.*<b>Authorized Administrators&#58;</b>|<b>Authorized Users&#58;</b>' `
    -ne '' `
    -replace '<.*'
).ForEach({
  # Extract admin lines and user lines each, as an array.
  , ($_ -split '\r?\n' -ne '')
})

# Clean up the $admins array and transform the username-password pairs
# into custom objects with .username and .password properties.
$admins = $admins -split '\s+password&#58;\s+' -ne ''
$i = 0;
$admins.ForEach({ 
  if ($i++ % 2 -eq 0) { $co = [pscustomobject] @{ username = $_; password = '' } } 
  else { $co.password = $_; $co } 
})

# Create custom objects with the same structure for the users.
$users = $users.ForEach({
  [pscustomobject] @{ username = $_; password = '' }
})

# Output to CSV files.
$admins | Export-Csv admins.csv
$users | Export-Csv users.csv
$admins + $users | Export-Csv all.csv
```

Assumptions are made about the desired output format (and HTML entities such as `&amp;` aren't decoded), given that your question doesn't flesh out the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt to get what you are after.

```
$url        = '<THE URL TAKEN FROM THE .URL SHORTCUT FILE>'
$outputPath = '<THE PATH WHERE YOU WANT THE CSV FILES TO BE CREATED>'

# get the content of the web page
$html = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url).Content

# load the assembly to de-entify the HTML content
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$html = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($html)

# get the Authorized Admins block
if ($html -match '(?s)<b>Authorized Administrators:</b>(.+)<b>') {
    $adminblock = $matches[1].Trim()
    # inside this text block, get the admin usernames and passwords
    $admins = @()
    $regex = [regex] '(?m)^(?<name>.+)\s*password:\s+(?<password>.+)'
    $match = $regex.Match($adminblock)
    while ($match.Success) {
        $admins += [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name'     = $($match.Groups['name'].Value -replace '\(you\)', '').Trim()
            'Type'     = 'Admin'
            # comment out this next property if you don't want passwords in the output
            'Password' = $match.Groups['password'].Value.Trim()    
        }
        $match = $match.NextMatch()
    } 

} else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find 'Authorized Administrators' text block."
}

# get the Authorized Users block
if ($html -match '(?s)<b>Authorized Users:</b>(.+)</pre>') {
    $userblock = $matches[1].Trim()
    # inside this text block, get the authorized usernames
    $users = @()
    $regex = [regex] '(?m)(?<name>.+)'
    $match = $regex.Match($userblock)
    while ($match.Success) {
        $users += [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name' = $match.Groups['name'].Value.Trim()
            'Type' = 'User'
        }
        $match = $match.NextMatch()
    } 
} else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find 'Authorized Users' text block."
}

# write the csv files
$admins | Export-Csv -Path $(Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath 'admins.csv') -NoTypeInformation -Force
$users | Export-Csv -Path $(Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath 'users.csv') -NoTypeInformation -Force
($admins + $users) | Export-Csv -Path $(Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath 'adminsandusers.csv') -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

When finished, you will have three CSV files:

**admins.csv**

```
Name   Type  Password      
----   ----  --------      
jim    Admin (blank/none)  
bob    Admin Littl3@birD   
batman Admin 3ndur4N(e&home
dab    Admin captain
```

**users.csv**

```
Name   Type
----   ----
bag    User
crab   User
oliver User
james  User
scott  User
john   User
apple  User
```

**adminsandusers.csv**

```
Name   Type  Password      
----   ----  --------      
jim    Admin (blank/none)  
bob    Admin Littl3@birD   
batman Admin 3ndur4N(e&home
dab    Admin captain       
bag    User                
crab   User                
oliver User                
james  User                
scott  User                
john   User                
apple  User
```

Answer (score -1):

this is really rather ugly, and very emphatically fragile. a good HTML parser would be a better way to do this.

however, presuming you aint got the resources for that, here's one way to grab the data. if you REALLY want to generate two more files [Admin & User], you can do that from this object ...

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
</p><ul><li>(None)</li></ul><h2><span style="font-size:18px;">Authorized Administrators and Users</span></h2><pre><b>Authorized Administrators&#58;</b>
jim (you)
    password&#58; (blank/none)
bob
    password&#58; Littl3@birD
batman
    password&#58; 3ndur4N(e&amp;home
dab
    password&#58; captain

<b>Authorized Users&#58;</b>
bag
crab
oliver
james
scott
john
apple
</pre><h2><span style="font-size:18px;">Competition Guidelines</span></h2>
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$CleanedInStuff = $InStuff.
    Where({
        $_ -notmatch '^</' -and
        $_ -notmatch '^ ' -and
        $_
        })

$UserType = 'Administrator'
$UserInfo = foreach ($CIS_Item in $CleanedInStuff)
    {
    if ($CIS_Item.StartsWith('<b>'))
        {
        $UserType = 'User'
        continue
        }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $CIS_Item.Trim()
        UserType = $UserType
        }
    }

# on screen
$UserInfo

# to CSV    
$UserInfo |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\LandonBB.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

on screen output ...

```
Name      UserType     
----      --------     
jim (you) Administrator
bob       Administrator
batman    Administrator
dab       Administrator
bag       User         
crab      User         
oliver    User         
james     User         
scott     User         
john      User         
apple     User
```

CSV file content ...

```
"Name","UserType"
"jim (you)","Administrator"
"bob","Administrator"
"batman","Administrator"
"dab","Administrator"
"bag","User"
"crab","User"
"oliver","User"
"james","User"
"scott","User"
"john","User"
"apple","User"
```